# Razor Page - Form with multiple handlers/server-side validation not populating asp-validation-for tags on submit

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, razor-pages, fluentvalidation

I have a form that is used to submit one of two objects. Using Fluent Validation, each object has separate validation rules, which are handled by executing ModelState.Clear() and TryValidateModel(objectName) in the respective post handler. Validation is working correctly, but is only displaying on the asp-validation-summary tag, not on the asp-validation-for tags that accompany each field. Does anyone have any idea how to get around this? (Using 2 forms is not an option.) Here is code you can use to replicate the issue:

TestValidation.cshtml:

```
@page
@model MyApp.Namespace.TestValidationModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>TestValidation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test Validation</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">ObjectToValidate1 - posts with empty handler, validates server side.</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Borrower Type</label>
                            <select asp-for="ObjectToValidate1.Item" asp-items="@Model.DDLItems" class="form-control" onchange="changeBorrowerType();"></select>
                            <span asp-validation-for="ObjectToValidate1.Item" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label"></label>
                            <label asp-for="ObjectToValidate1.RequiredString" class="control-label businessName"></label>
                            <input asp-for="ObjectToValidate1.RequiredString" class="form-control autofocus" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="ObjectToValidate1.RequiredString" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="ObjectToValidate1.RequiredStringIfItem1Selected" class="control-label"></label>
                            <input asp-for="ObjectToValidate1.RequiredStringIfItem1Selected" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="ObjectToValidate1.RequiredStringIfItem1Selected" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" asp-page-handler="">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">ObjectToValidate2 - posts with handler of TestValidation, validates serverside</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        @*<div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Borrower Type</label>
                            <select asp-for="ObjectToValidate2.Item" asp-items="@Model.DDLItems" class="form-control" onchange="changeBorrowerType();"></select>
                            <span asp-validation-for="ObjectToValidate2.Item" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label"></label>
                            <label asp-for="ObjectToValidate2.RequiredString" class="control-label businessName"></label>
                            <input asp-for="ObjectToValidate2.RequiredString" class="form-control autofocus" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="ObjectToValidate2.RequiredString" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="ObjectToValidate2.RequiredStringIfItem1Selected" class="control-label"></label>
                            <input asp-for="ObjectToValidate2.RequiredStringIfItem1Selected" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="ObjectToValidate2.RequiredStringIfItem1Selected" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" asp-page-handler="TestValidation">Submit</button>
                        </div>*@
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    @*<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.11/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>*@
</body>
</html>
```

TestValidation.cshtml.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using FluentValidation;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;

namespace MyApp.Namespace
{
    public class TestValidationModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public InputValues ObjectToValidate1 { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public InputValues ObjectToValidate2 { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> DDLItems { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            ObjectToValidate1 = new InputValues();
            ObjectToValidate2 = new InputValues();
            InitializeDDLItems();
        }

        public ActionResult OnPost()
        {
            ModelState.Clear();
            TryValidateModel(ObjectToValidate1);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Refresh current page
                return RedirectToPage("./TestValidation");
            }
            InitializeDDLItems();
            return Page();
        }
        public ActionResult OnPostTestValidation()
        {
            ModelState.Clear();
            TryValidateModel(ObjectToValidate2);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Refresh current page
                return RedirectToPage("./TestValidation");
            }
            InitializeDDLItems();
            return Page();
        }
        private void InitializeDDLItems()
        {
            DDLItems = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem("-- Select an Item -- ", ""),
                new SelectListItem("Item 1", "1"),
                new SelectListItem("Item 2", "2"),
            };
        }
    }
    public class InputValues
    {
        [Display(Name ="Item")]
        public int Item { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Required String")]
        public string RequiredString { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Conditional Required String")]
        public string RequiredStringIfItem1Selected { get; set; }
    }
    public class Validator : AbstractValidator<InputValues>
    {
        public Validator()
        {
            RuleFor(i => i.Item).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Item is required");
            RuleFor(i => i.RequiredString).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Required String is required");
            When(i => i.Item.Equals(1), () =>
            {
                RuleFor(e => e.RequiredStringIfItem1Selected).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Conditional Required String is required if Item 1 selected");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer: Don't use ModelState.Clear(). Doing so clears out the ModelState to the extent that, even after running TryValidateModel(modelname), the resulting ModelState doesn't have enough to enable the validation tags to render. So, here is a simplified version of my earlier sample, with ModelState.Clear() commented out and ModelState.ClearValidationState() run for each object that we want to validate server side. To run for my original code, above, I would ClearValidationState for the fields that are not relevant to the current OnPost method.

The Razor Page:

```
@page
@model MyApp.Namespace.TestValidation2Model
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>TestValidation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test Validation</h1>
    <form method="post">
        @*<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>*@
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">ObjectToValidate1 - posts with empty handler, validates server side.</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Borrower Type</label>
                            <select asp-for="ObjectToValidate1.Item" asp-items="@Model.DDLItems" class="form-control" onchange="changeBorrowerType();"></select>
                            <span asp-validation-for="ObjectToValidate1.Item" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label"></label>
                            <label asp-for="ObjectToValidate1.RequiredString" class="control-label businessName"></label>
                            <input asp-for="ObjectToValidate1.RequiredString" class="form-control autofocus" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="ObjectToValidate1.RequiredString" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="ObjectToValidate1.RequiredStringIfItem1Selected" class="control-label"></label>
                            <input asp-for="ObjectToValidate1.RequiredStringIfItem1Selected" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="ObjectToValidate1.RequiredStringIfItem1Selected" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" asp-page-handler="">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    @*<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.11/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>*@
</body>
</html>
```

The PageModel:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using FluentValidation;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;

namespace MyApp.Namespace
{
    public class TestValidation2Model : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public InputValues2 ObjectToValidate1 { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> DDLItems { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            ObjectToValidate1 = new InputValues2();
            InitializeDDLItems();
        }

        public ActionResult OnPost()
        {
            ModelState.ClearValidationState(nameof(ObjectToValidate1.RequiredString));//.Clear();
            ModelState.ClearValidationState(nameof(ObjectToValidate1.Item));//.Clear();
            ModelState.ClearValidationState(nameof(ObjectToValidate1.RequiredStringIfItem1Selected));
            //ModelState.Clear();
            TryValidateModel(ObjectToValidate1);
            var jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ModelState);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Refresh current page
                return RedirectToPage("./TestValidation2");
            }
            InitializeDDLItems();
            return Page();
        }
        private void InitializeDDLItems()
        {
            DDLItems = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem("-- Select an Item -- ", ""),
                new SelectListItem("Item 1", "1"),
                new SelectListItem("Item 2", "2"),
            };
        }
    }
    public class InputValues2
    {
        [Display(Name = "Item")]
        public int Item { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Required String")]
        public string RequiredString { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Conditional Required String")]
        public string RequiredStringIfItem1Selected { get; set; }
    }
    public class Validator2 : AbstractValidator<InputValues2>
    {
        public Validator2()
        {
            RuleFor(i => i.Item).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Item is required");
            RuleFor(i => i.RequiredString).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Required String is required");
            When(i => i.Item.Equals(1), () =>
            {
                RuleFor(e => e.RequiredStringIfItem1Selected).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Conditional Required String is required if Item 1 selected");
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following javascript files which support client-side validation :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryvalidate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.11/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

> The jQuery Unobtrusive Validation script is a custom Microsoft front-end library that builds on the popular jQuery Validate plugin. Without jQuery Unobtrusive Validation, you would have to code the same validation logic in two places: once in the server-side validation attributes on model properties, and then again in client-side scripts.

Reference :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.0#client-side-validation

Comment: If I add the validate and unobtrusive scripts (which are commented out in my sample), the entire form validates, which is not what i want. I only want the right-hand part of the form to validate if that button is clicked and the left-hand part of the form to validate if that button is clicked.

Comment: If you want to implement the partial  validation, you could try to  customize the jQuery for [client-side validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2#custom-client-side-validation) or use the remote validation .

Comment: We are wanting to stick with server-side fluent validation, rather than client-side jquery validation. However, I have isolated the issue. As soon as the lines ModelState.Clear() and  TryValidateModel() execute, ModelState.IsValid resolves correctly but the ModelState is not passed to the razor page in a form that would enable it to render the validation tags correctly.